# Nginx Config - Serve Angular2 App

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration

I've an Angular2 SPA, I've added the language as suffix to urls, like this:

www.mywebsite.com/en

If I load directly from nodejs webserver in this way  ->  www.mywebsite.com:4500/en
the request is correctly handled by angular of course.

Now when I'm using nginx I don't know how to tell to nginx that urls with language suffix must be handled by index.html.

In the nginx config file I've setup some other location that are working fine. 
Only this configuration is needed.

With the following settings, nginx reply 404 and the nginx errorlog file report:

***appfolder/dist/client/en  (no such file or directory)***

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /appfolder/dist/client;
    index index.html;

    location ~ /(fr|en|es|it) {       
       root /appfolder/dist/client;
    }


    location /{      
      return 301 /en$uri;
    }

    other location's without conflict with this

}
```

I've tried a lot of other configurations by search on google but without result.

How can I tell to nginx that I want that url with languages has to be handled by index file?

Answer (score 0):

I've found one solution that seems to work, better solution are welcome

Set the location in this way

```
   location / {}

   location /it {
        alias /project/dronedesign/dist/client;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location /en {
        alias /project/dronedesign/dist/client;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```